# Change AJAX url with a variable inside success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call that I need to loop over to achieve pagination.

I want to grab a value during each run from the success function, stick it back in the URL that AJAX is pulling and then run the next loop.

How can I change the AJAX url based on something I can find in the success data?

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of example. Here's my function as is now...

```
for (var i=0; i < 8; i++) {
        $.ajax({
        'url': 'https://someurl.com?paramone=xxx,
        timeout: 8000,
        'success': function(data) {
           //do something with data
       }
```

I'd like to change paramone's value each time through the loop

Comment: Why aren't you running all your information on the server side and just returning the completed data after those loops?

Comment: @CayceK Because we heavily cache our site so our processing needs to be done on client side (JS).

Answer (score 1):

Just create a convenient function and call it again

```
function doAjax(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url  : url,
        type : 'GET',
        data : 'something',
        dataType : 'json'
    }); 
}

doAjax('mypage1.php').done(function(data) {

    doAjax( data.url ).done(function(data2) {
        // do something after second ajax call ?
    });

});
```

It's hard to be more specific when the question is so generic, and lacks an example of what you're really trying to do ?

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the question with my existing code. Can you advise how to integrate your solution into my code?